# The Hamiltonian for clocks?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian-formalism

I am rather a theoretician and looking for a formalism to represent biological clocks by Hermitian operators.

The simplest thought model I am looking for is a formal representation of a clock (for instance 12 hours clock) by applying a Hermitian operator (e.g. Hamiltonian)?

*Note: a clock is a discrete modular representation*

As questions came up, let me try to explain:

A clock has a modular arithmetic, that is a discrete oscillator, for instance:
$$a \equiv b \pmod n$$

Many biological clocks work like this, and our 12 hours clock is similar $\pmod {12}$.

It is possible as Raskolnikov indicated to apply an inverse Fourier type of approach and express such clocks, as discrete as they are, in the form of a sum such as (example):

$$\psi_q=\sum_{k=1}^q \frac{\omega_q}{4 \pi} \left( e^{-i(k-1)\;\omega_q x} + e^{i(k-1)\;\omega_q x}\right)$$

Both are the representation of the same type of clock.

My first question is *how does the parameters in the first equation relate to the second equation?*

My second question is *then what is the Hermitian operator of the second equation?*

My third question is *how can I find to a type of algorithm or general method to read the first equation directly into a Hermitian operator?*

The fact that I use this for biological clocks is marginal. The $\pmod n$ operation is independent of where we use it.

I hope this helps, but if still questions, I am glad to explain.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. $U=e^{i\omega t}$ is just fine, it has period $T=2\pi/\omega$. It's unitary and therefore associated to the Hermitian operator $H=\omega$.

Comment: That is potentially very interesting but I do not understand it yet ... Can you explain in a bit more sencences (maybe with LaTex too ...) what a clock is? And what exactly would this Hermition operator do? Maybe it is just me and people more knowledgable dont need further explanations ;-) ...

Comment: I have not understood either. Considering adjective "biological" I realized that it is not related to quantum mechanics

Comment: @freude: I am from Leuven. Maybe we can carry this on in a chatroom?

Comment: I think you are looking for operators that behave similar to creation/annihilation ones. I mean in the sense that there can be a change of the state of the system  depending on time, and which returns back to the initial state with certain periodicity. If this is the case, I think you need to define what quantity(ies) are relevant to you, because that will determine the form of your operators, and at the same time constrain your definition.